# Analytics in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, analytics

I use the MVVM in my project moreover I have analytics service outside the entire MVVM, but I don't know where call to analytics service, in ViewModels or in ViewCotrollers?

Example:

VIEW MODEL

```
login.request{ result in 
    //Here??
    Firebase.registerUser()
    viewController.finishLoginDelegate()
}
```

VIEW CONTROLLER

```
func finishedLoginDelegate() {
    //Or Here??
    Firebase.registerUser()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rather very interesting question. I have not read any blogs/documents dealing with the Analytics wrt MVVM.

In Analytics, there can be some cases where events are needed to be send for different stages of view lifecycle, whereas there would be some cases where only data matters. Couple this with the fact that most of the analytics are needed by Project Managers and they normally don't include them in specs, it becomes rather difficult to factor them  when thinking about an app's or feature's architecture.

I have been guilty of putting a lot of analytics code in ViewControllers even when following MVVM. But, now when I think of it, I guess it is prudent to include an analytics layer(like ViewModel), for purely analytics related code. We can call it AnalyticsModel(for lack of better name).

We can write protocols related to it, pass on data and events from ViewController/ViewModel to this object and it can call Analytics API (is it me or there are just too many nowadays) and everybody can go back to assuming that they are happy in their own little world.

I have written the below code, to show how you can try writing AnalyticsModel.

```
protocol LoginAnalyticsModelProtocol {
    func loginViewAppeared()
    func loginButtonPressed(user:User)
    func signUpButtonPressed()
}


class LoginAnalyticsModel:LoginAnalyticsModelProtocol {
    func loginViewAppeared() {
        //call analytics to send login view appeared case
    }
    func loginButtonPressed(user:User) {
        // call analytics to send login view
    }
    func signUpButtonPressed() {
        // call analytics to submit sign up button pressed event
    }
}

class LoginVC:UIViewController {
    var loginVM:LoginViewModel?
    let loginAM:LoginAnalyticsModel = LoginAnalyticsModel()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        loginAM.loginViewAppeared()
    }

    @IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
        // Get user
        // call anaytics
        loginAM.loginButtonPressed(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: I always develop a Singleton Pattern for the Analytics API but I like very much your protocol Analytics pattern. I found this: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/architecting-an-analytics-layer-7cdacb5f74af   where use protocol and singleton pattern

Comment: @Alvaro: Thanks for the link. I have also used Publisher-Subscriber approach with singleton for one of my projects. Found it rather limiting after sometime, because there are some cases where two different analytics are in the app for different reasons and require altogether different data and events.

Comment: @PunnetSharma Anyway this doesn't answer my question....In your example, you include Analytics Services in the ViewController but can we include in the ViewModel? I think so...

Comment: @Alvaro: I have tried to make AnalyticsModel more like view model, where View controller is going to hold the object and pass on view related events. But if in case yo need analytics on purely business logic, you can inject it to ViewModel layer and continue sending events via this AnalyticsModel.

Comment: Yes, I will need analytics on business logic, in that case I will have to inject Analytics Api in the ViewModel...Thanks @puneet-sharma, very interesting your comments